# Access Controller method from another controller in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller

I have two controllers `SubmitPerformanceController` and `PrintReportController`.

In `PrintReportController` I have a method called `getPrintReport`.

How to access this method in `SubmitPerformanceController`?

Answer (score 480, accepted):

You can access your controller method like this:

```php
app('App\Http\Controllers\PrintReportController')->getPrintReport();
```

This will work, but it's bad in terms of code organisation (remember to use the right namespace for your `PrintReportController`)

You can extend the `PrintReportController` so `SubmitPerformanceController` will inherit that method

```php
class SubmitPerformanceController extends PrintReportController {
     // ....
}
```

But this will also inherit all other methods from `PrintReportController`.

The best approach will be to create a `trait` (e.g. in `app/Traits`), implement the logic there and tell your controllers to use it:

```php
trait PrintReport {

    public function getPrintReport() {
        // .....
    }
}
```

Tell your controllers to use this trait:

```php
class PrintReportController extends Controller {
     use PrintReport;
}

class SubmitPerformanceController extends Controller {
     use PrintReport;
}
```

Both solutions make `SubmitPerformanceController` to have `getPrintReport` method so you can call it with `$this->getPrintReport();` from within the controller or directly as a route (if you mapped it in the `routes.php`)

You can read more about traits [here](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Comment: where should the file including the trait be saved?

Comment: `app('App\Http\Controllers\PrintReportController')->getPrintReport();` can transformed to `app(PrintReportController::class')->getPrintReport()`. Clean solution for me.

Comment: Just a little example for using traits in Laravel: https://www.develodesign.co.uk/news/laravel-traits-what-are-traits-and-how-to-create-a-laravel-trait/

Comment: @Brainmaniac in `app/Traits`. More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40288806/5675325).

Comment: @VincentDecaux You forgot that `'` :-P. Remove it or it won't work

Answer (score 55):

If you need that method in another controller, that means you need to abstract it and make it reusable. Move that implementation into a service class (ReportingService or something similar) and inject it into your controllers.

Example:

```php
class ReportingService
{
  public function getPrintReport()
  {
    // your implementation here.
  }
}
// don't forget to import ReportingService at the top (use Path\To\Class)
class SubmitPerformanceController extends Controller
{
  protected $reportingService;
  public function __construct(ReportingService $reportingService)
  {
     $this->reportingService = $reportingService;
  }

  public function reports() 
  {
    // call the method 
    $this->reportingService->getPrintReport();
    // rest of the code here
  }
}
```

Do the same for the other controllers where you need that implementation. Reaching for controller methods from other controllers is a code smell.

Comment: Where would you save this class in terms of project structure?

Comment: Either a `Services` folder if the project is not big or a feature folder called `Reporting` if it's a bigger project and uses `Folders By Feature` structure.

Comment: Are you referring to a Service Provider (service class) like here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers or a Service Container like here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container?

Comment: @Baspa No, a normal PHP class.

Answer (score 43):

> Calling a Controller from another Controller is not recommended, however if for any reason you have to do it, you can do this:

**Laravel 5 compatible method**

```
return \App::call('bla\bla\ControllerName@functionName');
```

**Note:** this will not update the URL of the page.

It's better to call the Route instead and let it call the controller.

```
return \Redirect::route('route-name-here');
```

Comment: Why is it not recommended?

Comment: @Mahmoud Zalt where is the link of cite??

Comment: calling a controller action is not the same as redirect, so it is not "better".

Comment: About the not recommended, my opinion is because you are "skipping" many initialization or internal Laravel logic (which may not exist now, but in the future it will). Indeed you should not.

Comment: @KatLimRuiz Even if it doesn't skip initialization steps, calling the controller this way is slower compared to a direct instantiation of a class, because of so many internal calls. Instead, one should chunk the logic into smaller classes and call those instead.

Answer (score 19):

First of all, requesting a method of a controller from another controller is EVIL. This will cause many hidden problems in Laravel's life-cycle.

Anyway, there are many solutions for doing that. You can select one of these various ways.

### Case 1) If you want to call based on Classes

#### Way 1) The simple way

But you **can't add any parameters or authentication** with this way.

```php
app(\App\Http\Controllers\PrintReportContoller::class)->getPrintReport();
```

#### Way 2) Divide the controller logic into services.

You **can add any parameters and something** with this. The best solution for your programming life. You can make `Repository` instead `Service`.

```php
class PrintReportService
{
    ...
    public function getPrintReport() {
        return ...
    }
}

class PrintReportController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function getPrintReport() {
        return (new PrintReportService)->getPrintReport();
    }
}

class SubmitPerformanceController
{
    ...
    public function getSomethingProxy() {
        ...
        $a = (new PrintReportService)->getPrintReport();
        ...
        return ...
    }
}
```

### Case 2) If you want to call based on Routes

#### Way 1) Use `MakesHttpRequests` trait that used in Application Unit Testing.

I recommend this if you have special reason for making this proxy, you **can use any parameters and custom headers**. Also this **will be an internal request** in laravel. (Fake HTTP Request) You can see more details for the `call` method in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing).

```php
class SubmitPerformanceController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    use \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests;
    
    protected $baseUrl = null;
    protected $app = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        // Require if you want to use MakesHttpRequests
        $this->baseUrl = request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
        $this->app     = app();
    }

    public function getSomethingProxy() {
        ...
        $a = $this->call('GET', '/printer/report')->getContent();
        ...
        return ...
    }
}
```

However this is not a 'good' solution, too.

#### Way 2) Use guzzlehttp client

This is the most terrible solution I think. You **can use any parameters and custom headers**, too. But this would be making an external extra http request. So HTTP Webserver must be running.

```php
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => request()->getSchemeAndhttpHost(),
    'headers' => request()->header()
]);
$a = $client->get('/performance/submit')->getBody()->getContents()
```

Comment: Way 2 should not be written down there, you never want to self http-request yourself, even in a bad code structure.

Comment: Still existing as an option. Better than nothing

Answer (score 17):

You shouldn’t. It’s an anti-pattern. If you have a method in one controller that you need to access in another controller, then that’s a sign you need to re-factor.

Consider re-factoring the method out in to a service class, that you can then instantiate in multiple controllers. So if you need to offer print reports for multiple models, you could do something like this:

```
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function printReport()
    {
        $report = new PrintReport($itemToReportOn);
        return $report->render();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This approach also works with same hierarchy of Controller files:

```
$printReport = new PrintReportController;

$prinReport->getPrintReport();
```

Comment: I like this approach compared to the App::make one because the type hinting of the doc blocks still work in phpStorm this way.

Comment: @Floris to use type hinting, use it like this `App::make(\App\Http\Controllers\YouControllerName::class)`

Answer (score 15):

```
\App::call('App\Http\Controllers\MyController@getFoo')
```

Comment: Despite the fact that your answer might be correct, it would be nice to extend it a little and give some more explanation.

Answer (score 5):

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//call the controller you want to use its methods
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class MealController extends Controller
   {
      public function try_call( AdminController $admin){
         return $admin->index();   
    }
   }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 4):

You can use a static method in PrintReportController and then call it from the SubmitPerformanceController like this;

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PrintReportController extends Controller
{

    public static function getPrintReport()
    {
      return "Printing report";
    }


}



namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\PrintReportController;

class SubmitPerformanceController extends Controller
{


    public function index()
    {

     echo PrintReportController::getPrintReport();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access the controller by instantiating it and calling doAction: (put `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;` before the controller class declaration)

```
$controller = App::make('\App\Http\Controllers\YouControllerName');
$data = $controller->callAction('controller_method', $parameters);
```

Also note that by doing this you will not execute any of the middlewares declared on that controller.

Comment: Clean solution, thanks! Shouldn't be the way in a normal Laravel app, but in Themosis it is brilliant. Note that `$parameters` must be an array, even if there's only one or no parameters to the `controller_method`.

Answer (score 2):

Here the trait fully emulates running controller by laravel router (including support of middlewares and dependency injection). Tested only with 5.4 version

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline;
use Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher;
use Illuminate\Routing\MiddlewareNameResolver;
use Illuminate\Routing\SortedMiddleware;

trait RunsAnotherController
{
    public function runController($controller, $method = 'index')
    {
        $middleware = $this->gatherControllerMiddleware($controller, $method);

        $middleware = $this->sortMiddleware($middleware);

        return $response = (new Pipeline(app()))
            ->send(request())
            ->through($middleware)
            ->then(function ($request) use ($controller, $method) {
                return app('router')->prepareResponse(
                    $request, (new ControllerDispatcher(app()))->dispatch(
                    app('router')->current(), $controller, $method
                )
                );
            });
    }

    protected function gatherControllerMiddleware($controller, $method)
    {
        return collect($this->controllerMidlleware($controller, $method))->map(function ($name) {
            return (array)MiddlewareNameResolver::resolve($name, app('router')->getMiddleware(), app('router')->getMiddlewareGroups());
        })->flatten();
    }

    protected function controllerMidlleware($controller, $method)
    {
        return ControllerDispatcher::getMiddleware(
            $controller, $method
        );
    }

    protected function sortMiddleware($middleware)
    {
        return (new SortedMiddleware(app('router')->middlewarePriority, $middleware))->all();
    }
}
```

Then just add it to your class and run the controller. Note, that dependency injection will be assigned with your current route.

```php
class CustomController extends Controller {
    use RunsAnotherController;

    public function someAction() 
    {
        $controller = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\AnotherController');

        return $this->runController($controller, 'doSomething');
    }
}
```

Comment: Take in consideration that doing `app()->make(......)` is equals to `app(......)` so it is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

```
//In Controller A <br >
public static function function1(){

}


//In Controller B, View or anywhere <br>
A::function1();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for your time in answering this question. Can you please give more details about your solution? For example, why is your solution better than the accepted answer? Also, the question was asked and answered 5 years ago. Be sure to look at the date of the original question when answering. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a new PrintReportController object in SubmitPerformanceController and calling getPrintReport method directly.

For example lets say I have a function called "Test" in SubmitPerformanceController then I can do something like this:

```
public function test() { 
  $prc = new PrintReportController();
  $prc->getPrintReport();
 }
```

Comment: As far as better maintainability and flexibility `Trait` & `Service contract` should be the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the most elegant approach:

```
app(YourController::class)->yourControllerMethod()
```

Answer (score 2):

In SubmitPerformanceController add a constructor.

```
private $printReportController;
public function __construct(PrintReportController $printReportController)
{
     $this->printReportController = $printReportController;
}
```

Now you can call the getPrintReport function by using,

```
return $this->printReportController->getPrintReport();
```

Comment: This approach isn't recommended at all, please take a look at what other answers write about this

Comment: Not recommended? Why?

Comment: Why it is not recommended ? It looks like a classic dependecy injection

Answer (score 1):

1. Well, of course, you can instantiate the other controller and call the method you want. Probably it's not a good practice but I don't know why:

```php
$otherController = new OtherController();
$otherController->methodFromOtherController($param1, $param2 ...);
```

2. But, doing this, you will have a problem: the other method returns something like response()->json($result), and is not it what you want.
3. To resolve this problem, define the first parameter of the other controller's method as:

```php
public function methodFromOtherController(Request $request = null, ...
```

4. When you call methodFromOtherController from the main controller, you will pass null as first parameter value:

```php
$otherController = new OtherController();
$otherController->methodFromOtherController(null, $param1, $param2 ...);
```

5. Finally, create a condition at the end of the methodFromOtherController method:

```php
public function methodFromOtherController(Request $request = null, ...) 
{
  ...
  if (is_null($request)) {
    return $result;
  } else {
    return response()->json($result);
  }
}
```

6. Once Laravel will ever set $request when it is called by direct route, you can differentiate each situation and return a correspondent value.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but I have been looking for this for sometime. This is now possible in a very simple way.

Without parameters

```
return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
```

With Parameters

```
return redirect()->action('UserController@profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#redirecting-controller-actions

Back in 5.0 it required the entire path, now it's much simpler.

Comment: The original question was how to access a controller's method from other controller, not how to redirect to other specific method's action, so your solution is not related to the question.