# How to call controller action from Blade in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am trying to call controller action within view in Laravel 5.1, but unable to do this.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<?php echo BridesController::getPhotographer($data->sender_id);?>
```

but it is giving **Class 'BridesController' not found** error.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? For sure there are better ways than executing controller from a view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To render a foreign action output inside the view that belongs to your current action, you need to call the foreign action from your current action, then store its output to a variable and pass it to your current view.

### Calling actions from the same controller

If the action you want to render is inside the same controller you are using, you could call:

```
$result = $this->action();

return view('my.view',['my_rendered_action'=>$result]);
```

And then, inside your view, just:

```
{!! $my_rendered_action !!}
```

Take care of **not rendering** anything that comes from the user using this method, because {!! !!} tags won't scape dangerous inputs. If you do not need to have HTML inside your action response, always prefer using {{ }} instead.

### Calling actions from another controller

If you need to share a method between more than one controller, the cleanest way is to create a trait or a Job that implements the logic, and then both controllers would use the trait or dispatch the same job.

Please refer to [Shaddy's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365169/access-controller-method-from-another-controller-in-laravel-5?answertab=votes#answer-30365349) for more information.

Hope it helps. ;)

Comment: i tried your route solution in Laravel 5.4, but the result is just the url path and not the view. For example. when i call {{ action('page.listAll') }} the result is "http://localhost.indalpe/page/listAll". How to render the view returned from the action?

Comment: The route solution was marked as "Old Answer" because it was printing an URL. I edited the text now to remove its old version for clarity. To render the view, you need to store it in a variable before rendering. Please re-read the answer (I think it's clearer now).

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
action('BridesController@getPhotographer',$data->sender_id);
```

Ofcourse if you are using blade you can do this

```
{{ action('BridesController@getPhotographer',$data->sender_id) }}
```

You can check it here
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#basic-controllers

Answer (score 4):

If you create your own facade, you can do this.

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class BridesController extends Facade {

   protected static function getFacadeAccessor() {
       //what you want
       return 'getPhotographer';
   }

   public static function getPhotographer() {
       return "photographer";
   }

}
```

//May it be a service provider.

config/app.php

```
 'BridesController'=>  App\Http\Controllers\BridesController::class,
```

And then you can use in your view.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    {{BridesController::getPhotographer()}}
</div>
```

I haven't tested it, but I think that should work.