# Laravel - Running method of another controller in one controller

Tags: laravel

I have `UserController` and `PetController`.

In my `UserController`, I have `rewardUser()` method.

in my `PetController`, I'm using the `$user` variable which indicates the current logged in user.

How I can run my `rewardUser()` method from my PetController?

I've been trying to user `$user->rewardUser();` but for some reasons its not recognizing my method this way.

```
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::rewardUser()"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365169/access-controller-method-from-another-controller-in-laravel-5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

may be you should define the method `rewardUser()` in the User Model and import it with `use App\User`

Comment: Yep you are right. Defining method like that supposed to be in the Model and not in the Controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a trait.

Create a trait file, in `App\Common.php`, for e.g. Then copy the `rewardUser()` method to the trait.

Your trait file:

```
namespace App\Forum;


trait Common {

    public function rewardUser() {
         // Your code here...
    }

}
```

Then in your`UserController.php` and `PetController.php`, `use` the trait.

```
// UserController and PetController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers

use App\Common; // <- Your trait


class UserController extends Controller {

use Common // <- Your trait

    public function doSomething() {

        // Call the method from both your controllers now.
        $this-rewardUser();
    }
}
```

You can use the straight in as many controllers as you want and you can call the method in the straight using `$this->methodName()`.

Very simply and effective.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing some structure concepts, but if you really need it, you may use the container to do so:

```
$userController = app()->make(UserController::class);
return app()->call([$userController, 'rewardUser']);
```