# Laravel 5.2 Controller returning an object

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

I am having problems with a controller returning just an object. I have a tables types and in TypesController I want a function that will just return an array of types so I can use it in another controller so I wrote in TypesController:

```
public function getNavTypes()
    {
        $types = DB::table('v_itemtypes')->get();
        return ($types);
    }
```

I want to call this in another controller (authors) so I added the line

```
use App\Http\Controllers\TypeController;
```

And want to just call the object in my method to pass on to the view:

```
 public function getAuthor($author_id)
    {

        $author = Author::where('id', $author_id)->first();
        $navtypes = TypeController::getNavTypes;
        return view('authors.edit',['author'=>$author, 'navtypes'=>$navtypes]);
    }
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in AuthorController.php line 28: Undefined class constant 'getNavTypes'
```

Line 28 is

```
$navtypes = TypeController::getNavTypes;
```

As a newbie I am doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a function without instantiating its class except if the function is `static`. So either you change your function to `static`:

`public static function getNavTypes()`

Or you instantiate an object of the controller first:

```
$typeController = new TypeController();
$navtypes = $typeController->getNavTypes();
```

And ah btw since `getNavTypes` is a function, you need to add two brackets:

> ()

before its name when calling it. So change `$navtypes = TypeController::getNavTypes;` to `$navtypes = TypeController::getNavTypes();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Sorted now!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use TypeController::getNavTypes(), as getNavTypes is a method, not a class constant.

Answer (score 0):

Calling methods with `::` is only possible if you specified your method as `static`.

```php
public static function myMethod()
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

In your case, the method *is not* static so you need to call your method like this:

```php
$TypeController = new TypeController();
$navtypes = $TypeController->getNavTypes();
```

In Laravel you can also create a controller instance like this:

```php
$TypeController = App::make('TypeController');
$navtypes = $TypeController->getNavTypes();
```

**Note:**
Your `getNavTypes()` method logically belongs inside a Model or Repository class. So you better move it out of the controller and place it inside a model class of your choice - probably where it fits best regarding the context. In your controller mostly `action` methods should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

You can call controller methods in different controllers in Laravel 5 like:

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\TypeController')->getNavTypes()
```

Reference: [Access Controller method from another controller in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365169/access-controller-method-from-another-controller-in-laravel-5)

According to your code: `getNavTypes` is a method, not a static property or constant. You can call it this way

```
TypeController::getNavTypes();
```

Also declare this method static like before calling it:

```
public static function getNavTypes()
```