# Best practice to create new Master-Detail objects (Laravel 5.1)

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, extend, master-detail, traits

I've got 2 classes in my application both have their own Controller.
Week -> WeekController
Day -> DayController

When a new week is created I also want to create 5 (work)days for that week.

At this point I make a call from the create method in the WeekController to the create method in the DayController:

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\DayContoller')->create($week->id);
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365169/access-controller-method-from-another-controller-in-laravel-5) mentions this as being a bad practice.  The alternatives offered however don't seem better in my case:
A week doesn't really extend a day and using a trait would feel strange to me in this scenario as well.

So I wonder, what's the best solution in this scenario.  I'm pretty sure this is something that's pretty common.

**UPDATE**: Not quite sure if this is better but I already rewrote as follows:
I'm now injecting the DayController in the create method of the WeekController.

```
create(DayController $dayController, $id)
```

**UPDATE2**: I wrote a closure function in my route where I call a new written service.

```
function(CreateWeek $createWeek, $id) 
{
    $createWeek->createWeekWithDays($id);
} ]);
```

In this service I have a constructor that instantiates my 2 Controllers

```
public function __construct(WeekController $weekController, DayController $dayController)
{
    $this->weekController = $weekController;
    $this->dayController = $dayController;
}
```

and finally the createWeekWithDays method:

```
public function createWeekWithDays($id)
{
    //Create the week
    $newId = $this->weekController->create($id);

    // Create the days
    $this->dayController->createDays($newId);  
}
```

I don't know what's the best solution...

Comment: I think the post you linked to points to calling other controllers bad practice. I imagine you have models for `Week` and `Day`. Why not just create a week and 5 days in the Week controller?

Comment: That would be an option as well.  However I wanted to reuse the logic in the DayController's create method instead of replicating it.

Comment: Then extract that logic to another class (service maybe) and use it both in day controller and week controller

Comment: At this point I already rewrote my code, now injecting the DayController in the create method of the WeekController.
`create(DayController $dayController, $id)`

Comment: @PawelBieszczad I was actually trying to do that but at this point I don't manage how to get those service classes to work.  As far as I understand it's best to store as much business logic as possible in those classes but I don't see where they fit in the complete picture.  My route calls a controller and in that controller I bind/inject the service class, is that how it's supposed to be done?

Comment: Injecting controller is not how you want to do this. Can show the code for both `createDays` and `createWeek` method from your controllers? Are you using models?

Comment: Yes, I'm using models.  Here's the createWeek method:

`public function createWeek($id)
    {
        //Create the week

  $newWeek = new Week();
  $newWeek->id = ''; // Use AutoIncrement value of MySql 
  $newWeek->weekType ='U';
  $newWeek->created_at = Carbon::now();
  $newWeek->save(); 
  Debugbar::info($newWeek);
  return $newWeek->id;
    }`

The method for the days is similar except createDays loops 5 times over the createDay method.  Not much logic in here right now but the logic still needs to grow.