# How to make a Trait in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Where to make the file if i want to use this trait on my Models

How should this file look like if i want to have this trait inside:

```
trait FormatDates
{
    protected $newDateFormat = 'd.m.Y H:i';


    // save the date in UTC format in DB table
    public function setCreatedAtAttribute($date){

        $this->attributes['created_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);

    }

    // convert the UTC format to my format
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date){

        return Carbon::parse($date)->format($this->newDateFormat);

    }

    // save the date in UTC format in DB table
    public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($date){

        $this->attributes['updated_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);

    }

    // convert the UTC format to my format
    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date){

        return Carbon::parse($date)->format($this->newDateFormat);

    }

    // save the date in UTC format in DB table
    public function setDeletedAtAttribute($date){

        $this->attributes['deleted_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);

    }

    // convert the UTC format to my format
    public function getDeletedAtAttribute($date){

        return Carbon::parse($date)->format($this->newDateFormat);

    }
}
```

And how to apply it for example on a User Model class...

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Well, laravel follows `PSR-4` so you should place your traits in:

`app/Traits`

You then need to make sure you namespace your trait with that path, so place:

```
namespace App\Traits;
```

At the top of your `trait`

Then make sure when you save the file, the file name matches the trait name. So, if your trait is called `FormatDates` you need to save the file as `FormatDates.php`

Then 'use' it in your User model by adding:

```
use App\Traits\FormatDates;
```

at the top of your model, but below your `namespace`

and then add:

```
use FormatDates;
```

just inside the class, so for your User model, assuming you are using the laravel default, you would get:

```
use App\Traits\FormatDates;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, FormatDates;

...
}
```

And remember to dump the autoloader:

`composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I have created the file MyTraits.php and it's in the App\Traits folder and in my User Model Class i have namespace App\Traits; use App\Traits\FormatDates; use Notifiable, SoftDeletes, FormatDates; And it doesn't work...Trait cannot be found.....if you could help me please over TeamViewer???

Comment: Make sure you save the file as `FormatDates.php` to match your class name.

Comment: That fixed it....now i get another error Class '\App\User' not found..???

Comment: It looks like you've added a namespace to your User model, the namespace for the User model should be `namespace App;`, so make sure you haven't included `namespace App\Traits` in your User model

Comment: Do you have just 5 min please i have one more problem...i can't change the locale..it is changed in config/app.php but it doesn't apply

Comment: if we could chat somwhere to not to spam this question? Please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126844/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-craig-h).

Comment: @craig_h Great answer.  Could you update the top to say you are saving the file with name FormatDates.php in folder app/Traits.  I was a little confused till I saw your reply comments.  Would make the answer more complete.  +1

Comment: @craig_h Why should I use App\Traits\FormatDates; outside the class and then use FormatDates; again inside it ??

Comment: ^ that's how traits or any other class inside class are used. Otherwise you need to write the whole namespace of the trait/class you want to use and that can be very long and hard to read.

Comment: Where did you read that all traits should be in the `app/Traits` directory?

Comment: @LucasSilva I was probably just trying to keep things simple, but you can obviously put them wherever you want, just as long as your namespace matches the directory structure.

Comment: When I read this after 4 years... I admire @craig_h for his patience :D (I was at 3450 points at that time)

Answer (score 33):

To create a trait by command I do it like this:

```
  php artisan make:command TraitMakeCommand
```

then you have this command in app/Console/Commands

it will create this commands extending from Command, but you have to change it to GeneratorCommand that is the one used to create Classes, so instead:

```
  use Illuminate\Console\Command;
  class TraitMakeCommand extends Command{
```

you should have this:

```
  use Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand;
  class TraitMakeCommand extends GeneratorCommand{
```

then, delete __construct() and handle() methods cause you are not gonna need them.

You need to create a file in app/Console/Commands/stubs called traits.stub which is going to be the base for your trait:

```
  <?php

  namespace TraitNamespace;

  trait {{class}}
  {
   // 
  }
```

and the code should be like this:

```php
     /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'make:trait {name}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create a new trait';

    /**
     * The type of class being generated.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $type = 'Trait';

    /**
     * Get the stub file for the generator.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getStub()
    {
        return __DIR__ . '/stubs/traits.stub';
    }

    /**
     * Get the default namespace for the class.
     *
     * @param string $rootNamespace
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
    {
        return $rootNamespace . '\Traits';
    }
```

After all this, you can create a trait with this command:

```
php artisan make:trait nameOfTheTrait
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. But I cant make it work by simply copy paste. The signature should be `protected $signature = 'make:trait {name}';` and the stub should be  trait {{ class }} so that the class name will be automatically replaced.

Comment: You're welcome, I have edited the answer as you mentioned

Comment: You should replace 'TraitNamespace' by '{{namespace}} in your stub.

Answer (score 4):

Using this package you can create create Repository, Repository with Interface, Service, Trait form command line using php artisan command.

```
composer require theanik/laravel-more-command --dev
```

For create trait

```
php artisan make:trait {Trait Name}
```

Git repo : https://github.com/theanik/laravel-more-command