# Laravel search following the DRY principle

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have multiple search functions that all look something like this:

```
    public function searchEntity(Request $request)
    {       
        ... // Some variables and other stuff 

        $q = $request->q;
        $entities = Entity::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')->paginate(15);
        $entities->appends(['search' => $q]);
        return view(
            'entity',
            compact('entities', ...)
        );
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this where I don't repeat the same code each time I try to search an Eloquent entity or is it better to keep these methods separate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to create Trait with scope.

So you will have something like this in your trait:

```
trait search
{
    public function scopeSearch(Builder $builder)
    {
        $request = request();
        $q = $request->q;

        return $builder->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')->paginate(15);
    }

}
```

Than use your trait in your model. And in your controller for every model you can do like this:

```
$entities = Entity::search();
```

Just read about Traits and Scopes and I think that's what you need.

Some suggestions: [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288657/how-to-make-a-trait-in-laravel), [link-2](https://medium.com/@kshitij206/traits-in-laravel-5db8beffbcc3).

Good luck!

Comment: that isn't a scope

Comment: This is not the optimal way of doing it and should include a scope.

Comment: I said to create scope inside trait.