# Call controller function in another controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've a `PermissionController` with a `permission()` function like below, and i want to call the `permission()` function in another controller. How can i call my `permission()` function to another controller ?

here my `PermissionController`

```
class PermissionController extends Controller
{
    public function permission(){
    $checkPermission = User::leftJoin('employees', 'employees.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->leftJoin('positions', 'employees.position_id', '=', 'positions.id')
    ->leftJoin('divisions', 'employees.division_id', '=', 'divisions.id')
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('division_name', 'Sales')
                ->orWhere('division_name', '=', 'Project Management')
                ->orWhere('position_name', '=', 'Dept Head');
    })
    ->get();

    }   
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Controller method from another controller in Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365169/access-controller-method-from-another-controller-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your function should be in one of your model since you're only getting value.

This will me more relevant according to MVC.

Having it in your `User` model will let you use it on every instance of your application with a single call.

Answer (score 2):

Create new Helper (e.g `PermissionHelper.php`) then move the funtion to it and call it where you want using :

```
PermissionHelper::permission();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can call another controller's method, but this is terrible practice. Move you code to a model and call it with:

```
class PermissionController extends Controller
{
    public function permission()
    {
        $checkPermission = User::getEmployeePermissions();
    }
}
```

Do the same in other controllers' methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your PermissionController's "permission" method this way :

```
app(PermissionController::class)->permission();
```

However, be aware that this method isn't a good idea **at all**.

You have multiple refactoring options available ranging from the use of a helper class, a method on the concerned model or using a laravel job.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this

```
public function __construct(PermissionController $permission_controller)
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->permission_controller = $permission_controller;
}
```

Call any method like this

```
$this->permission_controller->permission();
```