# Laravel after ajax sucesss calling another controller with data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, url-routing

Currently I am able to pass my form data via ajax to my controller to insert into db. This works fine and after insert I will get data from the controller and pass to another controller only after this ajax is success. Currently stucked here cause I am using this method window.location.href.

```
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "{{ URL::asset('paysubmit') }}",
data: {eID:eID,amount:amount,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
success: function(data) {
    window.location.href = "{{ URL::asset('/cds') }}";
}
```

In the paysubmit controller currently I am using this method return `view('cds')->with($data);` but I need to do this in this ajax cause this codes are in php? I need to improvise on this  `window.location.href = "{{ URL::asset('/cds') }}";`?

Comment: Change `{{ URL::asset('/cds') }}` for `{{ url('cds') }}`

Comment: You want to pass data to some other method of other controller on ajax success. Right?

Comment: I want to pass data view('cds')->with($data);

Comment: @Rahul yes you are correct I want to pass data to some other method of other controller on ajax success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the two ways to solve your issue:

> - Make another call inside your ajax success function and pass the data received from your first call to second call.
> - In your first controller method after you get the data, call second controller method and then return the result.

What you are trying to achieve is not legit as you are returning a view to ajax success which is basically a html , and once you redirect to another url you will lost your data.

Comment: You can proceed to any of the above mentioned ways

Comment: I think, the second one is much more feasible solution.

Comment: depends on what you want to do with your data

Comment: @rahul how does this work in details In your first controller method after you get the data, call second controller method and then return the result.? Currently in my controller I have this  return view('cds')->with($data); but its not going to the controller either its keep returning to the first calling ajax function?

Comment: instead of returning view call other controller and pass data in the method

Comment: @rahul how to call another controller and pass the data rather than view what will the syntax be ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365169/access-controller-method-from-another-controller-in-laravel-5

Comment: @rahul I tried this return Redirect::route('cdscontroller/78'); it doesnt work either too

Comment: What you want to do exactly, why you redirecting

Comment: @rahul I want to redirect to that route itself cause I have defined this route  Route::get('cdscontroller/{ID}', 'CdsController@index'); I am getting error Route [cdscontroller] not defined

Comment: try return redirect()->route('route.name', [$param]);

Comment: @rahul its same

Comment: Well the issue is you has an ajax call so whatever you return will be passed to ajax success, so I think you need to try method 1

Comment: Are you returning id as 78 only from your first method

Comment: @rahul yes I am return 78 from my first method you are right on that

Comment: then in your ajax write `window.location.href = '/cdscontroller'+data`
where data is from success(data)

Answer (score 1):

You can write just another call within the `success` callback of your first ajax request. And use `data` received from your first call within your second ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "{{ '/home/view' }}",
    data: { eID:eID},
    success: function(data){
       if (data){
           $.ajax({
               method="POST",
               //other ajax settings here.
           })
       }
});
```

Comment: I dont want another ajax because once its ajax then it keep waiting at the back?