# Laravel, What is best approach to capture Visitors Ip?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, ip, refactoring

I'm searching for the best supported/secure approach to capture visitors Ip address.

At the moment I'm able to save visitor Ip by the following approach

Route from which call is made.

```
Route::get('/','VisitorController@multidisplay');
```

In multidisplay function, I'm calling another controller to capture and store Visitor Ip like->

```
 public function multidisplay()
    {   
        //calling log visitor controller
        app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\LogVisitIpController@store');


        return view('welcome')
        ->with('sliderimg', Sliderimage::all())
        ->with('postimg', PostImage::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get())
        ;

    }
```

and finally, the actual function to store visitor's Ip in LogVisitIpController

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $bla=$this->getIp();
        $myvisitor = new LogVisitIp();
        $myvisitor->visitorIp=$bla;
        $myvisitor->save();
    }
```

Now i have two question.

1. Is it ok to use a controller like that in another controller?
2. Should I use another approach to capture visitor ip using one
       controller?

Note: VisitorController is used to save request from the visitors in DB and send mail, I can collect IP and pass it from the visitor's request but my aim is to capture Ip as soon as the visitor open my website or make a ping request.

Comment: Do you have any login system or its for anyone who will visit your website's particular module ?

Comment: No, it's a one-page website. A visitor can only send a request as a guest.

Comment: Then its fine. You can use any way for storing visitor's IP the way you want. You have used a pretty nice approach using calling model for a single project.

Comment: It's a bad approach to call a function from one controller in any other controller according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30365349 I'm calling contranLogVisitIpController@store inside VisitorController@multidisplay. I want to use an eloquent model as middle man b/w two controllers  or any other better approach like php trait.

Answer (score 2):

Even if your code works actually, i would not recommend using that technique. 
Here is what you should do.

Define a class that is used only to save the ips. you will move your code that really logs the ip here.

```
Class VisitIpLoggerService
{
    public function storeIp(Request $request)
    {
        $myvisitor = new LogVisitIp();
        $myvisitor->visitorIp=$request->ip();
        $myvisitor->save();
    }
}
```

Then you will inject that service into your controller's function and call the function like that. That way your code will be easier to maintain.

```
public function multidisplay(Request $request, VisitIpLoggerService $ipLogger)
{   
    //just call the service
    $ipLogger->storeIp($request);
```

Comment: I would go even further and create a route middleware

Comment: Agreed. But i wanted to keep it simple in a way

Comment: LogVisitIpController is only used to capture IP address, the only difference b/w your approach and my approach is the way function store/storeip called/accessed in VisitorController. However, your way of calling looks clean. Also if used Laravel's built-in method to capture IP address, how do I find out if its the real IP aka not a proxy.

Comment: Just tested your approach. It doesn't worked out for me, it throws an exception  " BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\LogVisitIp::store()" .

Comment: @SyedAqeel i can't help with no code to inspect, post it somewhere and i would try to take a look...

Answer (score 0):

add this in your controller...

```
'ip_address_variable' => \Request::ip();
```

For your case,

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $bla=$this->getIp();
        $myvisitor = new LogVisitIp();
        $myvisitor->visitorIp=$request->ip();
        $myvisitor->save();
    }
```