# Laravel 4 how can I call another controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to call an external controller which is outside of `App`. Example path `project\domains\service\onion\controllers\SignupController.php`. In my `App->controller` got this class `exampleController`. So I try to get the function from `SignupController`.

Code

```
use Project\domains\service\onion\controllers\SignupController;

Class exampleController extends \RestController 
{
    public function grap()
        {
            $result = App::make('SignupController')->store();
        }
}
```

Got error: `Project\domains\service\onion\controllers\SignupController not found`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Controller method from another controller in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365169/access-controller-method-from-another-controller-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

You can try simply

```
(new SignupController())->methodOfSignupController();
```